# In mysql, why varchar require size and text does not?

Tags: mysql

Why does varchar require a specific size but text does not?

Comment: Because `text` is equal to `varchar(65535)` when it comes to storage requirement. Storing a lot of data is handled differently too.

Comment: I think it's a design decision. TEXT is limited to 65535. For other length there are differetn types, like tinytext and longtext...

Answer (score 3):

Obviously columns of type `text` also require storage space, but there is one fundamental difference to columns of type `char` or `varchar`:

The content of columns of type `text` is *not* stored inside the table itself, but at a separate location. That way the table itself does *not* get bloated by the huge space text cells actually require.

In contrary to that the cells of column types `char` or `varchar` are store right inside the table. Thus their size is considered in things like maximum index length and the like.